# Convert string like dict into dict format

Tags: python

I have a string that looks like the following:

```
{
change:"2.429993",
changePercent:"1.475316",
dayVolume:10222078,
exchange:NYQ,
id:CVX,
marketHours:1,
price:"167.14",
priceHint:4,
quoteType:8,
time:3304930430000,
}
```

I want to try and make this into a dict. I know that I can use `json.loads` to achieve this, however I do not know how to get the `keys` with double brackets.

Additionally, when I try parsing the string with the following:

```
type_of_dict.split(":")
```

It gives the following:

```
['{\nchange', '"2.429993",\nchangePercent', '"1.475316",\ndayVolume', '10222078,\nexchange', 'NYQ,\nid', 'CVX,\nmarketHours', '1,\nprice', '"167.14",\npriceHint', '4,\nquoteType', '8,\ntime', '3304930430000,\n}']
```

I can get it into a dict with a rather tedious process and was wondering if there are cleaner alternatives:

```
from collections import defaultdict
type_of_dict.split(":")
type_of_dict=[x.split(",\n") for x in type_of_dict]
keys=[x[1] for x in  type_of_dict[1:]][:-1]
keys  =[[x.split('\n') for x in type_of_dict[0]][0][1]] + keys
values = [x[0] for x in  type_of_dict[1:]]

symbols = defaultdict(list)
for k, v in zip(keys, values):
    symbols[k].append(v)
print(symbols)
```

```
defaultdict(<class 'list'>, {
    'change': ['"2.429993"'], 
    'changePercent': ['"1.475316"'], 
    'dayVolume': ['10222078'], 
    'exchange': ['NYQ'], 
    'id': ['CVX'], 
    'marketHours': ['1'], 
    'price': ['"167.14"'], 
    'priceHint': ['4'], 
    'quoteType': ['8'], 
    'time': ['3304930430000']
})
```

The script I used to grab the data:

```
import os
from subprocess import STDOUT, check_call as x
cmd1 = r'/Applications/StockSpy Realtime Stocks Quote.app/Contents/MacOS/StockSpy Realtime Stocks Quote'

with open(os.devnull, 'rb') as DEVNULL, open('output.txt', 'wb') as f:
    data=x(cmd1,  stdout=f, stderr=STDOUT)

with open('output.txt', 'r') as f:
    data=re.findall(r'\bsymbols:\s*\(\s*{[^{}]*}\s*\)', f.read())
```

Comment: **I know that I can use json.loads to achieve this** No you can't. JSON requires all the property names to be in double quotes.

Comment: On an additional note - what was wrong with my post so that I can improve it? I cannot seem to understand why I got so many downvotes given that I tried to explain my problem as best as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Could you provide more test data/records?

```py
import yaml
from pprint import pprint

data = """{
change:"2.429993",
changePercent:"1.475316",
dayVolume:10222078,
exchange:NYQ,
id:CVX,
marketHours:1,
price:"167.14",
priceHint:4,
quoteType:8,
time:3304930430000,
}"""

result_dict = yaml.safe_load(data.replace(':', ': '))
pprint(result_dict)
```

Result:

```sh
{'change': '2.429993',
 'changePercent': '1.475316',
 'dayVolume': 10222078,
 'exchange': 'NYQ',
 'id': 'CVX',
 'marketHours': 1,
 'price': '167.14',
 'priceHint': 4,
 'quoteType': 8,
 'time': 3304930430000}
```

After that if you want to cast types you can use pydantic:

```py
from pydantic import BaseModel

class Record(BaseModel):
    change: float
    changePercent: float
    dayVolume: int
    exchange: str
    id: str
    marketHours: int
    price: float
    priceHint: int
    quoteType: int
    time: int


dict(Record(**result_dict))
```

Result:

```py
{'change': 2.429993,
 'changePercent': 1.475316,
 'dayVolume': 10222078,
 'exchange': 'NYQ',
 'id': 'CVX',
 'marketHours': 1,
 'price': 167.14,
 'priceHint': 4,
 'quoteType': 8,
 'time': 3304930430000}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regular expression to add quotes around each key, then use `ast.literal_eval()` to parse it.

```
import ast
import re

dict_str = re.sub(r'^(.*?):', r"'\1':', type_of_dict)
result = ast.literal_eval(dict_str);
```

However, this will fail for `exchange:NYQ`. `NYQ` needs to be in quotes since it should be a string.

Comment: I have tested this and it does not work in my case. The original string is far too messy because of all the news lines it takes and so forth. I had thought of encasing the key's with double quotes, so I may look into a regex option for this as it does seem quicker.

Comment: The output of your attempt shows that the newlines are consistently placed, so I think this should work.